# Best method to query records and get count

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to query records from the DB using Entity Framework. I need to get the total count of records as well as the actual records. What is the best approach to do this

```
public IEnumerable<mFeedback> RetrieveAll(QueryOptions qOptions)
{
    if (qOptions == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(qOptions));

    using (_db)
    {
        var feedback = _db.Feedbacks
            .Where(f => f.isDeleted == false);

        if (qOptions.GetCount)
            qOptions.TotalRecordsCount = feedback.Count();

        feedback = feedback.OrderBy(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(qOptions.Sort) ? nameof(eFeedback.CreatedDate) : qOptions.Sort)
            .Skip(qOptions.Skip)
            .Take(qOptions.PageSize);

        return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<eFeedback>, IEnumerable<mFeedback>>(feedback.ToList());
    }
}
```

The current code i have is shown above. This produces 2 hits on the DB. Is there a better approach?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your approach is the best you can get from pure EF. Any attempt to combine the two queries will just make it worse.